# Unable to retrive data from SQLite says column doesn't exists in android (Eclipse)

Tags: android, eclipse, sqlite

I'm trying to fetch the data from SQLite using cursor method ,
but log cat keep saying.

I also gone through little details but i'm not getting whats wrong with the code.
It would be great pleasure if you guys point of my error's in codes.

```
             "java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.first/com.example.first.SqlView}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: KEY_ROWID (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_INTELLIGENCE FROM peopleTable"


            Follwing are the code files along with logs of logcat


        SqlLiteExample1 file

                package com.example.first;

            import com.example.first.R.dimen;

            import android.app.Activity;
            import android.app.Dialog;
            import android.content.Intent;
            import android.os.Bundle;
            import android.util.Log;
            import android.view.View;
            import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
            import android.widget.Button;
            import android.widget.EditText;
            import android.widget.TextView;

            public class SqlLiteExample1 extends Activity implements OnClickListener {


                Button saveToDataBase,retriveFromDataBase;
                public static final String TAG = "problem";
                EditText etName=null,etIntelligence=null;

                @Override
                protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                    setContentView(R.layout.sqllite);
                    initializer();
                }

                private void initializer() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    etName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etNamesqlLite);
                    etIntelligence = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etIntelligence);
                    saveToDataBase = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bUpdateDataBase);
                    retriveFromDataBase = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bRetriveDataBase);
                    saveToDataBase.setOnClickListener(this);
                    retriveFromDataBase.setOnClickListener(this);
                }

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    switch (v.getId()) {
                    case R.id.bUpdateDataBase:
                        boolean didItWork= true;
                        try {
                        String Name = etName.getText().toString();
                        String Intelligence = etIntelligence.getText().toString();
                        Log.e(TAG, " Poblem is not in fetching data from editText");    
                        IntelligentOtNot entry = new  IntelligentOtNot(SqlLiteExample1.this);
                        entry.open();
                        Log.e(TAG, " Poblem is not in method open");
                        entry.update(Name ,Intelligence);
                        Log.e(TAG, " Poblem is not in method update");
                        entry.close();
                        }catch (Exception e) {
                            // TODO: handle exception
                            didItWork = false;
                        }finally {
                            if(didItWork){
                                Log.e(TAG, " Poblem is not in if clause");
                                Dialog d = new Dialog( this);
                                d.setTitle("Oh yeah");
                                TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                                tv.setText("Success");
                                //tv.setTextSize("dp", "25");
                                d.setContentView(tv);
                                d.show();
                            }
                        }

                        break;

                    case R.id.bRetriveDataBase:

                        Intent i = new Intent("com.example.first.SQLVIEW");
                        startActivity(i);
                        break;
                    }

                }


            }





            SQLVIEW file





            package com.example.first;

            import android.app.Activity;
            import android.os.Bundle;
            import android.widget.TextView;


            public class SqlView extends Activity {

                TextView tvInfoFromDataBase;

                @Override
                protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                    setContentView(R.layout.viewsqllite);


                    tvInfoFromDataBase = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvSqlInfo);


                    IntelligentOtNot info = new IntelligentOtNot(this);
                    info.open();
                    String sqlData = info.getData();
                    info.close();
                    tvInfoFromDataBase.setText(sqlData);


                }

            }



    file IntelligentOtNot



    package com.example.first;

    import java.util.Currency;

    import android.R.string;
    import android.content.ContentValues;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.database.SQLException;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
    import android.util.Log;

    public class IntelligentOtNot {

        public static final String KEY_ROWID = "Rid";
        public static final String KEY_NAME = "persons_name";
        public static final String KEY_INTELLIGENCE = "persons_intelligence";

        private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "IntelligentOrNotDb";
        private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "peopleTable";
        private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
        public static final String TAG = "problem";
        private DbHelper ourHelper;
        private final Context ourContext;
        private SQLiteDatabase ourDataBase;

        private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

            public DbHelper(Context context) {
                super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
                // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            }

            @Override
            public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.e(TAG, " onCreate method of SQLite is called");
                db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" + KEY_ROWID
                        + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + KEY_NAME
                        + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_INTELLIGENCE
                        + " TEXT NOT NULL );");
                Log.e(TAG, " Query Executed successfully");

            }

            @Override
            public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
                onCreate(db);

            }

        }

        public IntelligentOtNot(Context c) {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            ourContext = c;
        }

        public IntelligentOtNot open() throws SQLException {
            ourHelper = new DbHelper(ourContext);
            ourDataBase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            return this;
        }

        public IntelligentOtNot close() {
            ourHelper.close();
            return null;
        }

        public long update(String name, String intelligence) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
            cv.put(KEY_NAME, name);
            cv.put(KEY_INTELLIGENCE, intelligence);
            return ourDataBase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);

        }

        public String getData() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub 

            String[] columns = { "KEY_ROWID", "KEY_NAME", "KEY_INTELLIGENCE" };

            Cursor c = ourDataBase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);

            String result = "";
            int iRow = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
            int iName = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME);
            int iIntelligence = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_INTELLIGENCE);

            for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {

                result = result + c.getString(iRow) + " " + c.getString(iName)
                        + " " + c.getString(iIntelligence) + "\n";

            }
            return result;
        }
    }




LOGCAT:



10-30 00:58:56.902: W/ApplicationPackageManager(4199): getCSCPackageItemText()
10-30 00:58:56.902: I/PersonaManager(4199): getPersonaService() name persona_policy
10-30 00:58:57.132: E/MoreInfoHPW_ViewGroup(4199): Parent view is not a TextView
10-30 00:58:57.232: D/dalvikvm(4199): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 94K, 37% free 17030K/26660K, paused 17ms, total 18ms
10-30 00:58:57.252: I/dalvikvm-heap(4199): Grow heap (frag case) to 32.260MB for 12582928-byte allocation
10-30 00:58:57.342: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(4199): native_setup
10-30 00:58:57.342: V/MediaPlayer(4199): constructor
10-30 00:58:57.342: V/MediaPlayer(4199): setListener
10-30 00:58:57.342: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(4199): setDataSourceFD: fd 54
10-30 00:58:57.342: V/MediaPlayer(4199): setDataSource(54, 104515, 3969752)
10-30 00:58:57.352: V/MediaPlayer(4199): message received msg=8, ext1=0, ext2=0
10-30 00:58:57.352: V/MediaPlayer(4199): notify(8, 0, 0) callback on disconnected mediaplayer
10-30 00:58:57.382: V/MediaPlayer(4199): setVideoSurfaceTexture
10-30 00:58:57.382: V/MediaPlayer(4199): prepare
10-30 00:58:57.392: V/MediaPlayer(4199): message received msg=200, ext1=973, ext2=0
10-30 00:58:57.392: W/MediaPlayer(4199): info/warning (973, 0)
10-30 00:58:57.392: V/MediaPlayer(4199): callback application
10-30 00:58:57.392: V/MediaPlayer(4199): back from callback
10-30 00:58:57.392: V/MediaPlayer(4199): message received msg=5, ext1=0, ext2=0
10-30 00:58:57.392: V/MediaPlayer(4199): New video size 0 x 0
10-30 00:58:57.392: V/MediaPlayer(4199): callback application
10-30 00:58:57.392: V/MediaPlayer(4199): back from callback
10-30 00:58:57.392: V/MediaPlayer(4199): message received msg=1, ext1=0, ext2=0
10-30 00:58:57.392: V/MediaPlayer(4199): prepared
10-30 00:58:57.392: V/MediaPlayer(4199): signal application thread
10-30 00:58:57.392: V/MediaPlayer(4199): callback application
10-30 00:58:57.392: V/MediaPlayer(4199): prepare complete - status=0
10-30 00:58:57.392: V/MediaPlayer(4199): back from callback
10-30 00:58:57.402: I/MediaPlayer(4199): Don't send intent. msg.arg1 = 0, msg.arg2 = 0
10-30 00:58:57.402: E/MediaPlayer(4199): Should have subtitle controller already set
10-30 00:58:57.422: D/TextLayoutCache(4199): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
10-30 00:58:57.442: I/Adreno-EGL(4199): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:  ()
10-30 00:58:57.442: I/Adreno-EGL(4199): OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.24.00.08+13
10-30 00:58:57.442: I/Adreno-EGL(4199): Build Date: 03/28/14 Fri
10-30 00:58:57.442: I/Adreno-EGL(4199): Local Branch: 0328_AU200_patches
10-30 00:58:57.442: I/Adreno-EGL(4199): Remote Branch: 
10-30 00:58:57.442: I/Adreno-EGL(4199): Local Patches: 
10-30 00:58:57.442: I/Adreno-EGL(4199): Reconstruct Branch: 
10-30 00:58:57.482: D/OpenGLRenderer(4199): Enabling debug mode 0
10-30 00:58:57.512: D/TextLayoutCache(4199): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
10-30 00:58:57.602: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(4199): release
10-30 00:58:57.602: V/MediaPlayer(4199): setListener
10-30 00:58:57.602: V/MediaPlayer(4199): disconnect
10-30 00:58:57.602: V/MediaPlayer(4199): destructor
10-30 00:58:57.602: V/MediaPlayer(4199): disconnect
10-30 00:58:57.622: W/ApplicationPackageManager(4199): getCSCPackageItemText()
10-30 00:58:57.632: E/MoreInfoHPW_ViewGroup(4199): Parent view is not a TextView
10-30 00:58:57.672: D/AbsListView(4199): Get MotionRecognitionManager
10-30 00:58:57.692: D/AbsListView(4199): onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 4
10-30 00:58:57.692: D/AbsListView(4199): unregisterIRListener() is called 
10-30 00:58:57.702: D/AbsListView(4199): onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 0
10-30 00:58:57.702: D/AbsListView(4199): unregisterIRListener() is called 
10-30 00:58:57.722: D/AbsListView(4199): unregisterIRListener() is called 
10-30 00:58:57.752: D/TextLayoutCache(4199): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
10-30 00:58:57.762: D/TextLayoutCache(4199): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
10-30 00:58:57.762: D/TextLayoutCache(4199): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
10-30 00:58:57.762: D/TextLayoutCache(4199): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
10-30 00:58:57.762: D/TextLayoutCache(4199): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
10-30 00:58:57.772: D/TextLayoutCache(4199): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
10-30 00:58:57.772: D/TextLayoutCache(4199): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
10-30 00:58:57.772: D/TextLayoutCache(4199): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
10-30 00:58:57.782: D/TextLayoutCache(4199): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
10-30 00:58:57.782: D/TextLayoutCache(4199): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
10-30 00:58:57.782: D/TextLayoutCache(4199): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
10-30 00:58:57.782: D/TextLayoutCache(4199): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
10-30 00:58:57.792: D/TextLayoutCache(4199): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
10-30 00:58:57.792: D/AbsListView(4199): unregisterIRListener() is called 
10-30 00:58:57.802: D/TextLayoutCache(4199): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
10-30 00:58:57.802: D/TextLayoutCache(4199): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
10-30 00:58:57.802: D/TextLayoutCache(4199): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
10-30 00:58:57.802: D/TextLayoutCache(4199): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
10-30 00:58:57.802: D/TextLayoutCache(4199): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
10-30 00:58:57.802: D/TextLayoutCache(4199): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
10-30 00:58:57.802: D/TextLayoutCache(4199): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
10-30 00:58:57.802: D/TextLayoutCache(4199): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
10-30 00:58:57.802: D/TextLayoutCache(4199): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
10-30 00:58:57.802: D/TextLayoutCache(4199): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
10-30 00:58:57.812: D/TextLayoutCache(4199): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
10-30 00:58:57.812: D/TextLayoutCache(4199): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
10-30 00:58:57.812: D/TextLayoutCache(4199): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
10-30 00:58:57.832: D/AbsListView(4199): unregisterIRListener() is called 
10-30 00:58:57.852: D/AbsListView(4199): unregisterIRListener() is called 
10-30 00:58:59.342: D/TextLayoutCache(4199): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
10-30 00:58:59.352: D/TextLayoutCache(4199): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
10-30 00:59:00.492: D/AbsListView(4199): unregisterIRListener() is called 
10-30 00:59:00.492: W/ApplicationPackageManager(4199): getCSCPackageItemText()
10-30 00:59:00.512: E/MoreInfoHPW_ViewGroup(4199): Parent view is not a TextView
10-30 00:59:00.572: D/TextLayoutCache(4199): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
10-30 00:59:01.012: D/AbsListView(4199): onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 4
10-30 00:59:01.012: D/AbsListView(4199): unregisterIRListener() is called 
10-30 00:59:02.162: D/TextLayoutCache(4199): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
10-30 00:59:02.162: D/TextLayoutCache(4199): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter

10-30 00:59:05.132: E/problem(4199):  Poblem is not in fetching data from editText
10-30 00:59:05.152: E/problem(4199):  onCreate method of SQLite is called
10-30 00:59:05.152: E/problem(4199):  Query Executed successfully
10-30 00:59:05.162: E/problem(4199):  Poblem is not in method open
10-30 00:59:05.172: E/problem(4199):  Poblem is not in method update
10-30 00:59:05.172: E/problem(4199):  Poblem is not in if clause
10-30 00:59:05.242: D/TextLayoutCache(4199): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
10-30 00:59:08.312: W/InputEventReceiver(4199): Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.
10-30 00:59:08.312: W/InputEventReceiver(4199): Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.
10-30 00:59:08.312: W/ViewRootImpl(4199): Dropping event due to root view being removed: MotionEvent { action=ACTION_MOVE, id[0]=0, x[0]=392.0, y[0]=685.0, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=8998225, downTime=8998211, deviceId=9, source=0x1002 }
10-30 00:59:08.352: E/ViewRootImpl(4199): sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
10-30 00:59:11.282: W/ApplicationPackageManager(4199): getCSCPackageItemText()
10-30 00:59:11.302: E/MoreInfoHPW_ViewGroup(4199): Parent view is not a TextView
10-30 00:59:11.332: E/SQLiteLog(4199): (1) no such column: KEY_ROWID
10-30 00:59:11.332: D/AndroidRuntime(4199): Shutting down VM
10-30 00:59:11.332: W/dalvikvm(4199): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4174cda0)
10-30 00:59:11.342: E/AndroidRuntime(4199): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-30 00:59:11.342: E/AndroidRuntime(4199): Process: com.example.first, PID: 4199
10-30 00:59:11.342: E/AndroidRuntime(4199): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.first/com.example.first.SqlView}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: KEY_ROWID (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_INTELLIGENCE FROM peopleTable
10-30 00:59:11.342: E/AndroidRuntime(4199):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2292)
10-30 00:59:11.342: E/AndroidRuntime(4199):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2350)
10-30 00:59:11.342: E/AndroidRuntime(4199):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:163)
10-30 00:59:11.342: E/AndroidRuntime(4199):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1257)
10-30 00:59:11.342: E/AndroidRuntime(4199):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
10-30 00:59:11.342: E/AndroidRuntime(4199):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
10-30 00:59:11.342: E/AndroidRuntime(4199):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5335)
10-30 00:59:11.342: E/AndroidRuntime(4199):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-30 00:59:11.342: E/AndroidRuntime(4199):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-30 00:59:11.342: E/AndroidRuntime(4199):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
10-30 00:59:11.342: E/AndroidRuntime(4199):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
10-30 00:59:11.342: E/AndroidRuntime(4199):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-30 00:59:11.342: E/AndroidRuntime(4199): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: KEY_ROWID (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_INTELLIGENCE FROM peopleTable
10-30 00:59:11.342: E/AndroidRuntime(4199):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
10-30 00:59:11.342: E/AndroidRuntime(4199):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1113)
10-30 00:59:11.342: E/AndroidRuntime(4199):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:690)
10-30 00:59:11.342: E/AndroidRuntime(4199):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
10-30 00:59:11.342: E/AndroidRuntime(4199):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
10-30 00:59:11.342: E/AndroidRuntime(4199):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
10-30 00:59:11.342: E/AndroidRuntime(4199):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
10-30 00:59:11.342: E/AndroidRuntime(4199):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1430)
10-30 00:59:11.342: E/AndroidRuntime(4199):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1277)
10-30 00:59:11.342: E/AndroidRuntime(4199):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1148)
10-30 00:59:11.342: E/AndroidRuntime(4199):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1316)
10-30 00:59:11.342: E/AndroidRuntime(4199):     at com.example.first.IntelligentOtNot.getData(IntelligentOtNot.java:89)
10-30 00:59:11.342: E/AndroidRuntime(4199):     at com.example.first.SqlView.onCreate(SqlView.java:24)
10-30 00:59:11.342: E/AndroidRuntime(4199):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5389)
10-30 00:59:11.342: E/AndroidRuntime(4199):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
10-30 00:59:11.342: E/AndroidRuntime(4199):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2256)
10-30 00:59:11.342: E/AndroidRuntime(4199):     ... 11 more
10-30 01:04:11.372: I/Process(4199): Sending signal. PID: 4199 SIG: 9
10-30 01:04:11.722: W/ApplicationPackageManager(6061): getCSCPackageItemText()
10-30 01:04:11.722: I/PersonaManager(6061): getPersonaService() name persona_policy
10-30 01:04:11.772: E/MoreInfoHPW_ViewGroup(6061): Parent view is not a TextView
10-30 01:04:11.802: D/AbsListView(6061): Get MotionRecognitionManager
10-30 01:04:11.822: D/AbsListView(6061): onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 4
10-30 01:04:11.822: D/AbsListView(6061): unregisterIRListener() is called 
10-30 01:04:11.832: D/AbsListView(6061): onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 0
10-30 01:04:11.832: D/AbsListView(6061): unregisterIRListener() is called 
10-30 01:04:11.842: D/AbsListView(6061): unregisterIRListener() is called 
10-30 01:04:11.852: D/TextLayoutCache(6061): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
10-30 01:04:11.872: I/Adreno-EGL(6061): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:  ()
10-30 01:04:11.872: I/Adreno-EGL(6061): OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.24.00.08+13
10-30 01:04:11.872: I/Adreno-EGL(6061): Build Date: 03/28/14 Fri
10-30 01:04:11.872: I/Adreno-EGL(6061): Local Branch: 0328_AU200_patches
10-30 01:04:11.872: I/Adreno-EGL(6061): Remote Branch: 
10-30 01:04:11.872: I/Adreno-EGL(6061): Local Patches: 
10-30 01:04:11.872: I/Adreno-EGL(6061): Reconstruct Branch: 
10-30 01:04:11.932: D/OpenGLRenderer(6061): Enabling debug mode 0


10-30 01:04:11.962: D/AbsListView(6061): unregisterIRListener() is called
```

Answer (score 1):

It's typo mistake.

Use `KEY_ROWID` not `"KEY_ROWID"`

Your table name is

```
public static final String KEY_ROWID = "Rid";
public static final String KEY_NAME = "persons_name";
public static final String KEY_INTELLIGENCE = "persons_intelligence";
```

And in your get method, you have written

```
String[] columns = { "KEY_ROWID", "KEY_NAME", "KEY_INTELLIGENCE" };
```

while it should be

```
String[] columns = { KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_INTELLIGENCE };

                          or 

String[] columns = { "Rid", "persons_name", "persons_intelligence" };
```

Comment: I got it Thank you @Dhaval Patel

Comment: @Kamil Accept the answer, If it help you to resolve your problem.